# How Silverstripe custom controller and view (template) works?

Tags: php, url-routing, silverstripe

I created the controller `./mysite/code/FileManager.php` with the following code...

```
class FileManager_Controller extends Controller
{
    public function upload()
    {
        echo 'It works!!';
    }
}
```

This works fine when I type `http://example.com/filemanager/upload`.

And I created the template file `themes/simple/templates/FileManager.ss`. I want to write the HTML for upload here and it should reflect when I type `http://example.com/filemanager/upload`. How to do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're using a straight controller to handle the request, the system doesn't know what you want to render or how. When using the CMS and rendering a `Page` this is usually taken care of for you.

So you have to tell it what to render and how. In it's simplest form this would look something like:

```
class FileManager_Controller extends Controller
{
    public function upload()
    {
        return $this->renderWith('FileManager');
    }
}
```

That will render your `FileManager_Controller` class with the `FileManager.ss` template.

Answer (score 1):

'upload' is an action in SilverStripe - have you tried creating a FileManager_upload.ss file ?